# Слово "старание"

Tags: этимология

Задумалась над словом "стараться". С одной стороны, это означает "стремиться сделать дело как можно лучше", "прилагать усердие". Но при это старателями почему-то называли золотодобытчиков. Интересно, почему именно их? Они что, больше всех старались?)))
И вообще, интересно было бы узнать происхождение слова "старание" и чем оно отличается от "усердия"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

СТАРАТЕЛЬ

У слова старатель отмечалось два значения:

1)Устар. деятель, рачитель, ревнитель, попечитель. По всему хороший был парень, к отцу, к матери почтительный, о братишке да об сёстрах заботливый, по дому во всём старатель. П. И. Мельников-Печерский, «На горах», 1875—1881 г.

2)Человек, добывающий золото кустарным способом. Пёстрые кучки старателей были рассыпаны по всему прииску; по ним можно было определить положение вашгердов, на которых совершалась промывка песков. Д. Н. Мамин-Сибиряк, «Золотуха», 1883.

Почему золотодобытчиков называют старателями? Можно предположить, что это синоним слова "предприниматель", отнесенный к горному делу. Такой вывод можно сделать из следующих текстов:

Золотодобыча велась как старательскими артелями, в которых рабочие старались на хозяина за жалование и харчи, так и вольными добытчиками «хищниками».

"В одиночку промывать золотой песок было очень сложно и опасно, поэтому искатели золота — обычно профессионалы и новички, романтики и авантюристы — собирались вместе в небольшую бригаду, которая на свой страх и риск шла штурмовать очередную россыпь. Это требовало особого упорства и старания, поэтому их называли старателями".

Также существует версия, что праслав. *starati (se) — первоначальное обозначение действия, связанного с обработкой руды, что считается менее вероятным

СТАРАТЬСЯ

Слово "стараться" отмечается в словарях только с 1731 года. В то же время и.-е. корень ster/stor широко известен по другим словам: стать, стоять, старый, стремиться. Его первоначальное значение - это стать прочным, крепким, твердым, сильным, достигшим полного развития.

УСЕРДИЕ, УСЕРДНЫЙ

Эти слова отмечаются с 11-13 веков, заимствование из ст.-сл. языка, от той же основы, что и сердце. Усердие буквально - труд от всего сердца.

Comment: "стать, стоять, старый, стремиться." - эти слова происходят от совершенно разных корней. Стать, стоять происходит от корня stea̯- а не ster-